# SAS table with percentage attached

Tags: sql, arrays, sas, correlation

I am trying to create a matrix with both numeric and percentage result. I was given two tables

```
id      cc
1       2
1       5
1       40
2       55
2       2
2       130
2       177
3       20
3       55
3       40
4       30
4       100


id      Description
1       Dell
1       Lenovo
1       HP
2       Sony
2       Dell
2       Acer
2       Other
3       Fujitsu
3       Sony
3       HP
4       Apple
4       Asus
```

I have already created a table that looks like..I used the code

```
CC        CC1     CC2…  …CC177
1         264     5        0
2         0      132       6
…
…
177       2        1      692

data RESULT;
set id_CC;
by id;
retain CC1-CC177;  /*CC range from 1 to 177*/
array CC_List(177) CC1-CC177;

if first.id then do i=1 to 177;
   id_LIST(i)=0;
end;

CC_List(CC)=1;

if last.id then output;

run;


ods output sscp=coocs;
ods select sscp;
proc corr data=RESULT sscp;
var CC1-CC177;
run;
/*proc print data=coocs;*/
/*run;*/
/**/
```

In other words, how many id have cc1 also have cc2..cc177..etc. Now, I am wondering if it's doable to add percentage next to each number. For instance if CC1*CC1=264 (100%) then CC1*CC2= 5/264=1.9%

Another table I am trying to create is to have description of each CC on the matrix. Each CC number stands for one brand. 2=Dell 177=Other, etc. I want to create a table looks like 
If I want to change the CC1 CC2 to characters, how do I modify the arrays? Eventually, I would like my table looks like

```
Description   Dell    Lenovo    HP    Sony   Acer   Other    Fujitsu    Sony  
Dell        264 (100%)
Lenovo
 HP                    50 (10%)
Sony
Acer
Other
Fujitsu
Sony
```

In other words, how many people have dell also have acer, sony, other, etc?

Comment: Thanks Joe! I'll make the correction. I'm very new to SAS.

Comment: Kelly, I think you need to post what you've tried for this to be a valid SO question.  You can try other forums - SAS-L or communities.sas.com for more help as well.

Comment: Reeza, thanks for all your help! I used your code to get the results. Can you let me know how to add percentage next to each number?

Answer (score 0):

The rename is a question that's been asked on here so I'll leave that one for now.

For the percentages you'll need to create a character variable. TO calculate the percent use the automatic variable `_n_`  which is the row, but will also be the denominator for your calculation. Then use a concatenate function such as cats to create the variable in the format N(PP%).

```
data want;
set have;
array cc(177) cc1-cc177;
array dd(177) $ dd1-dd177;

do i=1 to 177;
   percent=cc(i)/cc(_n_); 
   dd(i)=cats(cc(i), "(", put(percent, percent8.1), ")");
end;

run;
```

Comment: I keep getting this message: ERROR 68-185: The function CC is unknown, or cannot be accessed. The error occurs on the percent line.

Comment: Did you call the array CC or CC_List in your code? Make sure it's consistent.

Answer (score 0):

In answering Reeza, I did:

```
data RESULT_PRE;
set ID_CC;
by ID;
retain CC1-CC177;
array CC_LIST(177) CC1-CC177;
array DD_LIST(177) $ DD1-DD177;

if first.id then do i=1 to 177;
   CC_LIST(i)=0;

end;

CC_LIST(CC)=1;

if last.id then output;

run;

data RESULT;
set RESULT_PRE;

array CC_LIST(177) CC1-CC177;
array DD_LIST(177) $ DD1-DD177;

do i=1 to 177;
   percent=CC_LIST(i)/CC_LIST(_n_); 
   DD_LIST(i)=cats(CC_LIST(i), "(", put(percent, percent8.1), ")");
end;

run;
```

The error shows that Array subscript out of range at line xx column xx and ERROR 68-185: The function CC is unknown, or cannot be accessed.

Comment: I'm not sure how to print correlation chart only displaying the DD results as well...

Comment: Your error doesn't match your code since your code doesn't show any CC() function.  I really think you should move your question to a different forum - communities.sas.com that is more conducive to a back and forth.

Comment: Thanks Reeza, I just created an account in communities.sas.com but I don't think I have the authorization to post questions as a new member. :(

Comment: You should right hand side at the bottom of the page, start a discussion.

Comment: Yep I did start a discussion but when I click on submit it won't let me. It needs to be approved.